# find chars/string in string from vector c++

Tags: c++11, find, c++

I have a vector of strings, and I want to count all 'Ace' in the vector. Right now I can only find one...

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("Ace of Spades");
    vec.push_back("Ace");
    string value = "Ace";
    int cnt = 0;
    auto iter = find_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](const string &str)
    {
        return str.find(value) != str.npos;
    });
    if(iter == end(vec))
        cout << "no found" << endl;
    else 
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
        cnt++;
        cout << cnt++ << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you don't *iterate* using the returned iterator, you just print the first one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
auto cnt = count_if(begin(vec), 
                    end(vec), 
                    [&](const string& str) {
                      return str.find(value) != std::string::npos;
                    });
```

Note that this only counts the number of strings containing `"Ace"`, not the total number of occurrences of `"Ace"` in the vector's elements.

Comment: Note also this will be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *count* the number of matching elements, you could use [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).
If you also need to do something with them, it would probably be best to forget about the standard library algorithms and use a ranged for like so:

```
int count = 0;
for (const auto& element : vec) {
    if (element.find(value) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
        ++count;
    }
}
std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why would you want to "forget about the [stl] algorithms" when you could just use `for_each` and a functor?

Comment: @ZacHowland Of course you can use `for_each`, but a ranged for loop is much clearer and more readable in my view. Algorithms are a great tool, but you don't have to use them *just to use them*.

Comment: I agree. In C++11, I find myself using `for_each` far less frequently than I used to.

Comment: @MartinNewhouse:  In general, I find that if I'm writing my own loop, I should refactor what I'm doing to be more readable, more flexible/reusable, and more maintainable.  Scott Meyers (and Herb Sutter, and a few others on the standards committee for that matter) have made that case for years:  http://www.drdobbs.com/stl-algorithms-vs-hand-written-loops/184401446.